# Finding all prime numbers satisfying the equation as follows

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers such that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{p+1} - \frac1q = \frac{4}{n+2},
\end{equation*}
for some positive integer $n$.
Find all possible value of $q-p$.

**Attempt:**
First of all, we must have $q-p>1$. Otherwise, there is no $n$ such that the equation above holds.

Next, I tried and found all $(p,q)$ that satisfying the equation above, that is,
$(2,5),(3,5),(2,7)$, and $(5,7)$. Thus, all possible value of $q-p$ are $2,3$, and $5$.

Also, I tried and found that for $q=11$, there is no $n$ such that the equation above holds, for all $p<11$. But, I couldn't prove it yet, that is, for $q≥11$, there is no positive integer $n$ such that the equation
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{p+1} - \frac1q = \frac{4}{n+2},
\end{equation*}
holds, for all $p<q$. How to prove it?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $(p+1)(q)(n+2)$ to clear the denominators.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang And then, what's next?

Comment: To those who reopened: note that the above equation is the *same* equation in the [dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105190/find-all-values-of-p-q-if-p-q-are-prime-and-q1-over-qp-over-p1-2n?noredirect=1&lq=1), but slightly rearranged (see the answers there). So this is an **exact dupe**, and the answers there are simpler. Please be more careful when evaluating reopen requests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all values of $p-q$ if $p, q$ are prime and ${q+1\over q}+{p\over p+1}={2n\over n+2}$ where $n$ is a positive integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105190/find-all-values-of-p-q-if-p-q-are-prime-and-q1-over-qp-over-p1-2n). Note that Barry Cipra's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3105350/602049) states that this other question's equation can be rewritten (actually relatively simply) to the same form as shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1. $p=2$: $1/3-1/q=4/(n+2)$, $(q-3)(n+2)=12q$, $q>3$. $q-3$ is coprime with $q$, so $q-3$ divides $12$, $q-3=1,2,3,4,6,12$, $q=4,5, 6, 7, 9, 15$. Only $q=5, 7$ are possible. Then $n=28, 19$.

Case 2. $p>2$. Then $(q-p-1)/(q(p+1))=4/(n+2)$
Note that $q-p-1$ is odd. Hence $n+2$ is divisible by $4$, $n+2=4k$:

$$(q-p-1)/(q(p+1))=1/k$$

So $q-p-1$ must divide $q(p+1)$. Since $q-p-1<q$, it is coprime with $q$, so it divides $p+1$. That is a sufficient condition too.

For example
$q-p-1=1$ which means $q-p=2$, $q$ and $p$ are twin primes always works.

**Edit.** Let us analyze the iff condition further:
$q-p-1$ divides $p+1$. So if we denote $q-p-1=a$, we  have that $a| p+1$. Then $a|(q-p-1)+(p+1)=q$. Since $q$ is prime, $a=1$. So **the only** valid pairs $p,q$ where $p>2$ are twin primes.

Comment: For $p=3$ and $q=5$, $1/4 - 1/5 = 1/20 = 4/80$ and so $n=78$.

Comment: $p=11, q=13$ also works, see the edited version. In general $p,q$ tween primes work always.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. Emm... What does "tween primes" means?

Comment: And then, there are infinitely many $(p,q)$ satisfies the equation above, unless $q-p=2$. Isn't it?

Comment: Thus, $q-p=2,3,5$ and hence there are only $3$ possibilities for the value of $q-p$. Isn't it?

Comment: Primes are called twins if $|q-p|=2$. I made a misprint (twice).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your help sir. I got it right now.

Comment: @kuahmi: I think I have to make another correction.

Comment: @kuahmi: I have made a (hopefully final) edit. The only good pairs with $p>2$ are twin primes. Sorry for the many edits.

Comment: It's okay, Sir. No problem with those edits. Once again, thanks.

Comment: I think there is a mistake again sir. It must be $a \mid (q-p-1) + (p+1)$, isn't it?

Comment: @kuahmi: Yes!${}{}$